# Updating nested MongoDB document object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord

*Hello there, a quick MongoDB mixed with some Discord knowledge question:*

So currently, I want a formation for my MongoDB Document similar to the following:

```
channels: {
    utility:{
        suggestions: String
    },
    logging: {
        main: String,
        channel: {
            channelCreate: String,
            channelDelete: String,
            channelUpdate: String,
        },
        role: {
            roleCreate: String,
            roleDelete: String,
            roleUpdate: String,
        }
}
```

This saves channel IDs so users can decide where each event will be logged. I have this set up in the schema and all good, but when I do `findOneAndUpdate` I don't know how to edit a single field; for example, let's say I want to edit `roleDelete` which is inside `channels.logging.role` how would I do that? because doing

```js
await doc.updateOne({channels:{logging:{role:{roleDelete: IDHERE}}}});
```

It does not work. In fact, it screws everything up and replaces everything within `channels` to the value given, so how would I go around actually updating ONE value without messing with everything else? Thank you so much for your attention and participation.

This is using NodeJS Mongoose NPM Package btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved this by doing the following:

```
await doc.updateOne({ 'channels.logging.role.roleDelete': IDHERE}, { new: true, upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true });
```

This updated the value if it existed and created it if it didn't exist. Using the above methods uses `$set` internally. ([Read more here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update))

Feel free to ask if I didn't make myself clear

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `$set` operator. you can find details on https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/index.html

```
doc.updateOne({ _id: ID }, {
        $set: {
            channels.logging.role.roleDelete: IDHERE
        }
}
```